# Raspberry Pi - GPIO in Python

Tags: pip, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to get my Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins working, and I am following *[Tutorial: How to use your Raspberry Pi like an Arduino](http://log.liminastudio.com/writing/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-like-an-arduino)*.

( I'm working through SSH running Raspbian.) I have successfully installed distribute.

When trying to install PIP, I get the error shown below.

How can I fix it?

```
    pi@DuckPi ~ $ sudo curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100 85929  100 85929    0     0  89250      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  103k
    Downloading/unpacking pip
      Running setup.py egg_info for package pip

        warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
        warning: no previously-included files matching '*.txt' found under directory 'docs/_build'
        no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build/_sources'
    Installing collected packages: pip
      Running setup.py install for pip
        error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip': Permission denied
        Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/pi/build/pip/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-6djiJW-record/install-record.txt:
        running install

    running build

    running build_py

    running install_lib

    creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip

    error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip': Permission denied

    ----------------------------------------
    Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/pi/build/pip/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-6djiJW-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
    Storing complete log in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `curl` was `sudo`ed instead of `python`. You must do:

```
$ curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | sudo python
```

Or if you prefer, download the file and then run it:

```
$ curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
$ sudo python get-pip.py
```

Comment: You can also use sudo easy_install3 -U pip to get the lastest version updated.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the same tutorial but instead of installing pip I just used:

```
sudo apt-get install rpi.gpio
```

The rest of the tutorial worked fine with a bit of searching around for some extra info.  My whole experience of simple GPIO introduction the subject of my blog post [Using Raspberry GPIO Interface](http://workingmatt.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/using-raspberry-pi-gpio-interface.html) which I hope helps too.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays the Debian packages are named:

```
python-rpi.gpio - Python GPIO module for Raspberry Pi
python3-rpi.gpio - Python 3 GPIO module for Raspberry Pi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the wiringPi library. It's very easy to use.

Here are the links:

For C: https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi

For Python: https://github.com/Gadgetoid/WiringPi2-Python

I hope it helps.